# ГОСТ 28147-89 в режиме простой замены

Tags: java, алгоритм, гост

Используя ключ

```
73 3d 2c 20 65 68 65 73 74 74 67 69 79 67 61 20 62 6e 73 73 20 65 73 69 32 6c 65 68 33 20 6d 54,
```

шифрую `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`. 
В начале разбиваю текст на две половины: `B = 00 00 00 00` и `A = 00 00 00 00` и ключ на 8 частей:

```
K1 = 33 20 6d 54,  
K2 = 32 6c 65 68,  
K3 = 20 65 73 69,  
K4 = 62 6e 73 73,  
K5 = 79 67 61 20,  
K6 = 74 74 67 69,  
K7 = 65 68 65 73,  
K8 = 73 3d 2c 20.
```

Затем складываю `A` с `K1` по модулю 2 в 32 степени, получаю `33 20 6d 54`.
В качестве таблицы замен использую:

```
{4, e, 5, 7, 6, 4, d, 1},  
{a, b, 8, d, c, b, b, f},  
{9, 4, 1, a, 7, a, 4, d},  
{2, c, d, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0},  
{d, 6, a, 0, 5, 7, 3, 5},  
{8, d, 3, 8, f, 2, f, 7},  
{0, f, 4, 9, d, 1, 5, a},  
{e, a, 2, f, 8, d, 9, 4},  
{6, 2, e, e, 4, 3, 0, 9},  
{b, 3, f, 4, a, 6, a, 2},  
{1, 8, c, 6, 9, 8, e, 3},  
{c, 1, 7, c, e, 5, 7, e},  
{7, 0, 6, b, 0, 9, 6, 6},  
{f, 7, 0, 2, 3, c, 8, b},  
{5, 5, 9, 5, b, f, 2, 8},  
{3, 9, b, 3, 2, e, c, c}.
```

3 заменяю на 2, 3 на c, 2 на 1, 0 на 7, 6 на d, d на c, 5 на f, 4 на 5.
Получаю `2c 17 dc f5`.
Циклический сдвиг влево на 11 бит даёт: `be e7 a9 60`
Далее полученный результат XOR B и получаю `be e7 a9 60`
Теперь сама проблема: После всех 32 шагов цикла результат должен быть равен `42 AB BC CE 32 BC 0B 1B` (пример из ГОСТ 34.11-94. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%A2_%D0%A0_34.11-94), но он получается другим. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно?

Пример кода:

```
private String encrypt(BigInteger[] key, String strForA, String strForB)  
{  
    int index = 0;  
    BigInteger A = new BigInteger(strForA, 16);  
    BigInteger B = new BigInteger(strForB, 16);  
    BigInteger interA = BigInteger.ZERO;  

    System.out.println("A = " + A.toString(16));

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("ЦИКЛ " + i);
        if (i < 24)
            index = i % 8;
        else
            index = 7 - (i % 8);
        interA = multiply(A, key[index]);
        interA = B.xor(interA);
        if (i < 31)
        {
            B = A;
            A = interA;
        }
        else
            B = interA;


    }

    String resultB = B.toString(16);
    String resultA = A.toString(16);

    while (resultB.length() % 2 != 0)
        resultB = 0 + resultB;
    while (resultA.length() % 2 != 0)
        resultA = 0 + resultA;

    return resultB + resultA;
}

private BigInteger multiply(BigInteger a, BigInteger b)
{
    BigInteger sum = a.add(b).mod(MODUL);

    String sumString = sum.toString(16);
    String newSumString = "";


    while (sumString.length() < 8)
        sumString = 0 + sumString;

    for (int i = 0; i < sumString.length(); i++)
    {
        newSumString += Integer.toString(ReplacementTable.table[Integer.parseInt(sumString.substring(i, i + 1), 16)][i], 16);
    }

    BigInteger result = new BigInteger(newSumString, 16);

    return shift(result);
}

private BigInteger shift(BigInteger number)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(number.toString(2));

    while (sb.toString().length() < 32)
        sb.insert(0, '0');
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        sb.append(sb.charAt(0));
        sb.deleteCharAt(0);     
    }

    String afterShift = sb.toString();

    return new BigInteger(afterShift, 2);
}
```

Comment: добавьте пример кода

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, добавил

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ошибся при делении ключа на 8 частей и при использовании таблицы замен. Необходимо было начинать заменять с конца строки.
ГОСТ 28147-89 в режиме простой замены. Алгоритм.
K – ключ.
A – младшие биты.
B – старшие биты.
Ключ K разбивается на 8 ключей, причём K = {K8, K7, K6, K5, K4, K3, K2, K1}.
A складывается с одним из 8 получившихся ключей по модулю 2 в степени 32.
Получаем S = (A + Ki) mod 2^32.
Полученное S разбивается на 8 частей, причём S = {S8, S7, S6, S5, S4, S3, S2, S1}.
Далее полученные 4-х битные символы преобразуются при помощи таблицы замен.
  Первым идёт S1, получается S1’, затем S2, получается S2’ и так далее.
После этой операции получаем S’ = {S8’, S7’, S6’, S5’, S4’, S3’, S2’, S1’}.
Далее полученное S’ циклически сдвигаем влево на 11 бит, получаем R.
Теперь, применяя операцию XOR, получим результат шага:
RESULT = R XOR B.
Производим перестановку:
B = A,
A = RESULT.
В цикле 32 шага. Первые 24 шага ключи подаются в порядке K1, K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, K8, K1, K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, K8, K1, K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, K8 . 
С шага 25 по 32 ключи подаются в обратном порядке: K8, K7, K6, K5, K4, K3, K2, K1.
После 32 шагов результат склеивается следующим образом – сначала идут младшие биты A, затем старшие биты B.

Подробный пример первого шага цикла.
K = 73 3d 2c 20 65 68 65 73 74 74 67 69 79 67 61 20 62 6e 73 73 20 65 73 69 32 6c 65 68 33 20 6d 54,
шифрую 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00. В начале разбиваю текст на две половины: B = 00 00 00 00 и A = 00 00 00 00 и ключ на 8 частей:
K8 = 73 3d 2c 20,
K7 = 65 68 65 73,
K6 = 74 74 67 69,
K5 = 79 67 61 20,
K4 = 62 6e 73 73,
K3 = 20 65 73 69,
K2 = 32 6c 65 68,
K1 = 33 20 6d 54.
Затем складываю A с K1 по модулю 2 в 32 степени, получаю 33 20 6d 54. В качестве таблицы замен использую таблицу замен ЦБ РФ:
{4, e, 5, 7, 6, 4, d, 1},
{a, b, 8, d, c, b, b, f},
{9, 4, 1, a, 7, a, 4, d},
{2, c, d, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0},
{d, 6, a, 0, 5, 7, 3, 5},
{8, d, 3, 8, f, 2, f, 7},
{0, f, 4, 9, d, 1, 5, a},
{e, a, 2, f, 8, d, 9, 4},
{6, 2, e, e, 4, 3, 0, 9},
{b, 3, f, 4, a, 6, a, 2},
{1, 8, c, 6, 9, 8, e, 3},
{c, 1, 7, c, e, 5, 7, e},
{7, 0, 6, b, 0, 9, 6, 6},
{f, 7, 0, 2, 3, c, 8, b},
{5, 5, 9, 5, b, f, 2, 8},
{3, 9, b, 3, 2, e, c, c}.
4 заменяю на d, 5 на d, d на 0, 6 на 9, 0 на 6, 2 на a, 3 на 1, 3 на 0
Получаю 01 a6 90 dd.
Циклический сдвиг влево на 11 бит даёт: 34 86 e8 0d
Далее полученный результат XOR B и получаю 34 86 e8 0d
Теперь
B = A = 00 00 00 00
A = 34 86 e8 0d

Результат 32 шагов будет
42 ab bc ce 32 bc 0b 1b